# Remove all unused dependencies from npm packages.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I inherited a react project that has a packages.json file with a ton of dependencies, many of which aren't even in the project.

**Is there some good tool or method for cleaning up packages.json, basically removing all the packages that are unused while keeping all that are needed?**

Right now I have to go line by line, remove a package, and then test the project & builds - and hope I didn't miss something, which seems very error prone.

Comment: building? Isn't there any `test` file?

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the `depcheck` which meet your requirement:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck

Comment: Seems this doesn't notice dependencies used in webpack

Comment: Dependencies used in Webpack loaders can be recognized with the special component of depcheck. You can refer to its document.

Comment: Even doing `depcheck . --specials=webpack` it still seems to ignore the webpack dependencies

Comment: @DonnyP maybe you can open an issue for it

Comment: Done: https://github.com/depcheck/depcheck/issues/194. There are many more like this. Time to look for alternatives I suppose.